# Como colocar online um programa?

Tags: python-3.x, web-service, servidor, tkinter, servidor-de-aplicação

Existe uma planilha (do google) compartilhada no qual vários usuários editam e a observam simultaneamente. Pra quem já usou a planilha compartilhada do google sabe que quando alguém começa a escrever todos enxergam em tempo real. Enfim eu construir um programa com algumas funcionalidades a mais para substituir essa planilha compartilhada (usei python 3.x e tkinter) **o problema é que eu não faço ideia de como colocar esse programa online** para vários usuários (no máximo 120) usarem simultaneamente. P.ex: alguém começou a digitar alguma coisa e todos verem (igual a planilha do google). Se alguém que entendeu o problema e puder pelo menos me orientar o que eu devo pesquisar/estudar serei eternamente grato !

ABAIXO UM PRINT DO PROGRAMA

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema é colocar online para que todos possam acessar ou que apareça em tempo real as modificações de cada usuário? Aliás, já aproveite para [edit] a pergunta e adicionar códigos relevantes para facilitar o entendimento do problema.

Answer (score 3):

Colocar online implica ligações de rede de cada utilizador. Cada ligação de rede vai ter uma latência. O processo de edição em tempo real por vários clientes numa rede é um grande desafio. Uma técnica utilizada é o uso de websockets.

O flow dos dados segue da seguinte forma genérica:

1. Utilizador A pede a página da planilla ao servidor
2. Utilizador B pede igualmente
3. Utilizador A envia um comando de edição para o servidor
4. O servidor faz um broadcast para todos os clientes ligados
5. Cada software cliente executa o comando recebido pelo broadcast.
6. O utilizador B observa em tempo real o comando de edição do utilizador A.